# Sharp 50LD264E CEC not working with OpenELEC on RPi

Tags: hdmi, openelec

I can't get HDMI-CEC to work with a Raspberry Pi running OpenELEC 4.2.1, with my old Samsung TV it worked correctly, but my new Sharp 50LD264E doesn't work. I've checked all the relevant settings on the TV and in XBMC. The TV is detected, see the cec-client scan output:

```
OpenELEC:~ # echo 'scan' | cec-client -s -d 1
opening a connection to the CEC adapter...
requesting CEC bus information ...
CEC bus information
===================
device #0: TV
address:       0.0.0.0
active source: no
vendor:        Vizio
osd string:    TV
CEC version:   1.4
power status:  on
language:      eng


device #1: Recorder 1
address:       1.0.0.0
active source: no
vendor:        Pulse Eight
osd string:    CECTester
CEC version:   1.4
power status:  on
language:      eng


currently active source: unknown (-1)
```

But that 'currently active source: unknown (-1)' is botherng me. Using cec-client I can actually turn of the TV using

```
echo 'standby 0.0.0.0' | cec-client -s -d 1
```

After which I can't get it to turn on again. None of the buttons on the TV remote contorl work in XBMC though.

In the TVs manual it says:

```
You need to programme the setting with remote control to control connected   devices�)
```

I have absolutely no idea what they are talking about ...

When I turn on debug logging in XBMC I get this:

```
11:42:53 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - >> 0f:80:00:00:10:00
11:42:53 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - >> TV (0) -> Broadcast (F): routing change (80)
11:42:53 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - Recorder 1 (1) was already marked as active source
11:42:53 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - >> source activated: Recorder 1 (1)
11:42:53 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - sending active source message for 'Recorder 1'
11:42:53 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - << powering on 'TV' (0)
11:42:53 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - << 10:04
11:42:53 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - << Recorder 1 (1) -> broadcast (F): active source (1000)
11:42:53 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - << 1f:82:10:00
11:42:53 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): menu state 'activated'
11:42:53 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - << 10:8e:00
11:42:54 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - >> 0f:84:00:00:00
11:42:54 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - >> TV (0) -> Broadcast (F): report physical address (84)
11:42:54 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - << Recorder 1 (1) -> broadcast (F): physical adddress 1000
11:42:54 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - << 1f:84:10:00:01
11:42:54 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - >> 0f:87:6b:74:6d
11:42:54 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - >> TV (0) -> Broadcast (F): device vendor id (87)
11:42:54 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - << Recorder 1 (1) -> Broadcast (F): vendor id Pulse Eight (1582)
11:42:54 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - << 1f:87:00:15:82
11:42:54 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - >> 01:46
11:42:54 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - >> TV (0) -> Recorder 1 (1): give osd name (46)
11:42:54 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): OSD name 'XBMC'
11:42:54 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - << 10:47:58:42:4d:43
11:42:55 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - >> 01:83
11:42:55 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - >> TV (0) -> Recorder 1 (1): give physical address (83)
11:42:55 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - << Recorder 1 (1) -> broadcast (F): physical adddress 1000
11:42:55 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - << 1f:84:10:00:01
11:42:55 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - >> 01:8c
11:42:55 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - >> TV (0) -> Recorder 1 (1): give device vendor id (8C)
11:42:55 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): vendor id Pulse Eight (1582)
11:42:55 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - << 1f:87:00:15:82
11:42:55 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - >> 01:46
11:42:55 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - >> TV (0) -> Recorder 1 (1): give osd name (46)
11:42:55 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): OSD name 'XBMC'
11:42:55 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - << 10:47:58:42:4d:43
11:42:57 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - >> 01:83
11:42:57 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - >> TV (0) -> Recorder 1 (1): give physical address (83)
11:42:57 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - << Recorder 1 (1) -> broadcast (F): physical adddress 1000
11:42:57 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - << 1f:84:10:00:01
11:43:01 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - >> 01:83
11:43:01 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - >> TV (0) -> Recorder 1 (1): give physical address (83)
11:43:01 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - << Recorder 1 (1) -> broadcast (F): physical adddress 1000
11:43:01 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - << 1f:84:10:00:01
11:43:01 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - >> 01:8c
11:43:01 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - >> TV (0) -> Recorder 1 (1): give device vendor id (8C)
11:43:01 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): vendor id Pulse Eight (1582)
11:43:01 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - << 1f:87:00:15:82
11:43:01 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - >> 01:46
11:43:01 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - >> TV (0) -> Recorder 1 (1): give osd name (46)
11:43:01 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): OSD name 'XBMC'
11:43:01 T:2963272784   DEBUG: CecLogMessage - << 10:47:58:42:4d:43
```

Which seems fine to me. Am I missing something here? Or should I just give up and hope the next vesion of openElec fixes it?

Comment: Helo,
I have the same problem and don't know what to do. I hope there is a possibility to make it work. Otherwise i've just spent money for nothing (This tv set is only for Raspbery pi :(

Comment: You can always use the iOS or Android app to control the Pi. But CEC is a lot easier, especially to navigate the menus.